# How to auto increment notifications badge number when receiving a push notification in iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, apple-push-notifications, ios13

Before iOS 13 I was incrementing the app badge number when a push notification arrived in the method `application :didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler`:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if application.applicationState == .background {
            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
        }
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
```

Then I cleaned the badge number every time the app was opened:

```
   func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
       UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
   }
```

The problem is that with the [latest changes in iOS 13](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707/?time=799) the method `application :didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` is only called if the push notification has the property `apns-priority` set to at least 5. We are using a third party push notification service that doesn't send push notifications with that property.

So my question is:

Is there any other way that I can take to automatically increase the app badge number when receiving a push notification?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to wake the app up and do it, this'll be left up to the system as to wake your app up or not. It's much better to have the system handle it, and include the badge number in the notification.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcontent/1649864-badge?language=objc